# Nature of NSString

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsstring

Such a basic question, but i don't know the answer.What exactly the difference between:

```
NSString *str = @"Hello";
```

and

```
NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"Hello"];
```

When should i use each one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When should i use each one?

```
NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"Hello"]; //1st one
```

The above is redundant, and has same meaning as

```
NSString *str = @"Hello"; //2nd one
```

So always use shorter one. i.e 2nd one in my example.

**EDIT:**

Also see this [What's the difference between NSString *s = @"string" and NSString *s = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"string"]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9034041/whats-the-difference-between-nsstring-s-string-and-nsstring-s-nsstri)

Comment: Yes, and the compiler emits a warning for the first one: `using 'initWithString:' with a literal is redundant`.

Comment: @MartinR: Your view on the edit link and comparing it with ARC.

Answer (score 4):

A `@""` expressions is replaced at compile time<sup>1</sup> with an instance of `NSConstantString`, which is a specialized subclass of `NSString` with a fixed memory layout<sup>2</sup>. This also explains why `NSString` is the only object that can be initialized at compile time<sup>3</sup>.

A `[[NSString alloc]initWithString:@""]` produces a NSString instance, initializes that instance with a literal expression, and releases the instance. Therefore, the object allocation is superfluous and immediately discarded. Which is why you should always use just the literal when creating immutable strings.

<sub><sup>1</sup> The LLVM code that rewrites the expression is `RewriteModernObjC::RewriteObjCStringLiteral` in [RewriteModernObjC.cpp](http://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project/cfe/trunk/lib/Rewrite/Frontend/RewriteModernObjC.cpp?revision=163050&view=markup).</sub>
<sub><sup>2</sup> To see the `NSConstantString` definition, cmd+click it in Xcode.</sub>
<sub><sup>3</sup> Creating compile time constants for other classes would be easy but it would require the compiler to use a specialized subclass. This would break compatibility with older Objective-C versions.</sub>

Comment: Btw, if you release the object created with `initWithString:` the release is ignored because your object pointer is already pointed to the `NSConstantString` instance, (at least in the current implementation of Clang), but the static analyzer of Xcode will still nag you to do it because implementing `initWithString:` as a literal is a feature of the compiler, not of the language.